# Unable to install libjpeg-turbo8-dev on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-13.10, libjpeg-turbo

I tried to install libjpeg-turbo8-dev like this.

```
feng@HP:~$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8-dev
[sudo] password for feng: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasyncns0:i386
  libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386

  {***many packages***}

  libxml2:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxt6:i386    
  libxxf86vm1:i386 mysql-common openjdk-7-jre-lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjpeg-turbo8-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/420 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 219 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 261347 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64 (from .../libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.3.0-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.3.0-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/jmorecfg.h', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo-devel 1.3.0-3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.3.0-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My Ubuntu is 13.10
I want to install libjpeg-turbo8-dev, because I want to install mysql-server and mysql-client. Thet depends on this package.

```
feng@HP:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8-dev (>= 1.1.90+svn722-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-client-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to install the synaptic package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2128682.html) is someone who had a similar problem with the java runtime. Maybe this can help you if synaptic doesn't.

Otherwise I am not sure if you do really need the dev package...

Comment: I tried it, but without libjpeg-turbo8, I can install noting on my ubuntu

Comment: @fengyl You can't install synaptic without libjpeg-turbo8? Then something is broken with your Ubuntu. Try asking on askubuntu, they are more likely able to help you!

Comment: @fengyl did they solve your problem? If so please edit the question for the solution or post it as answer for further reference.